# how to pass variable in route name in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have defined route

```
Route::get('/edit-industry/{id}', 'Industries@edit')->name('admin.editIndustry');
```

And passing variable by

```
{{ route('admin.editIndustry', ['id'=>1]) }}
```

OR

```
{{ route('admin.editIndustry', [1]) }}
```

This is not working. How to pass variable here?

Comment: `{{ route('admin.editIndustry/1') }}`

Answer (score 63):

wow, why are wrong answers (or answers for questions which were not asked in this case) upvoted?

EkinOf is correct, you can do

```
{{ route('admin.editIndustry', 1) }}
```

Btw your first one works too and is necessary, if you have more than 1 parameter

```
{{ route('admin.editIndustry', ['id'=>1]) }}
{{ route('admin.editIndustry', ['id'=>1, 'something'=>42]) }}
```

Comment: How can I pass an object as a route parameter and access its values in controller?

Answer (score 14):

If you have only one parameter you can do that :

```
{{ route('admin.editIndustry', 1) }}
```

Answer (score 12):

Simply try like this

**View**

```
{{URL::to('/edit-industry/1')}}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/edit-industry/{id}', 'Industries@edit')
```

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id){
    // use $id here
}
```

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 12):

Passing single parameter:

```
##Defining Route:##
Route::get('edit-industry/{id}', ['as' => 'admin.editIndustry', 'uses' => 'Industries@edit']);

##Calling Route:##
{{ route('admin.editIndustry',[$id]) }}
```

Passing multiple parameter:

```
##Defining Route:##
Route::get('edit-industry/{id}/{step}', ['as' => 'admin.editIndustry', 'uses' => 'Industries@edit']);

##Calling Route:##
{{ route('admin.editIndustry',[$id, $step]) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Directly pass with route name

```
{{ URL::to('/edit-industry/1') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [generating URLs from Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes) `route()`:

```
{{ route('admin.editIndustry', 1) }}
```

Using [URLs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#urls) url():

```
{{url('/edit-industry', [1])}}
```