# I have a PHP Laravel project, I want to add 2 variables to the URL

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a Laravel PHP webshop, where on each product I want to have its slug and image for its URL.

My route

```
Route::post('product/{slug}/{image}', [ProductController::class, 'details'])->name('products.details');
```

My function in the controller

```
public function details($id){
        $product = DB::select('SELECT * from products where id=?', [$id]);
        $category_id = DB::table('products')->where('id', $id)->value('categories_id');
        $slug = DB::table('categories')->where('id', $category_id)->value('slug');
        $image = DB::table('products')->where('id', $id)->value('image');
        return view('products-details', ['product'=>$product], ['slug'=>$slug], ['image'=>$image]);
    }
```

View

```
<form action="{{ action('App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController@details', $products->id) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      @csrf
    <div class="card">
        <img src="{{ asset('images/' . $products->image) }}" style="height:200px"  />
      <div class="container">
        <h4><b>{{ $products->name }}</b></h4> 
        <p>@if ($products->original_price != $products->selling_price)
            <div class="pricegreen">
                <h4>{{ $products->selling_price}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="pricered"> <h4> {{ $products->original_price }} </h4></div>
        @else
        <h4>{{ $products->selling_price }}</h4>
        @endif</p> 
        <button type="submit">Megtekintés</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I dont need to use the data, i just want to show it in the URL.

I have tried this in several variations including []-s and it only passes the first data:

```
<form action="{{ action('App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController@details', $products->id, $products->slug, $products->image) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Missing required parameter for [Route: products.details] [URI: product/{slug}/{image}] [Missing parameter: image].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass variable in route name in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752427/how-to-pass-variable-in-route-name-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have given a name to your router you can use `route` blade function in the blade file.

```
<form action="{{ route('products.details', ['slug' => $product->slug, 'image' => $product->image) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

also you can use the `compact` in the `details` function like below

```
public function details($id){
    $product = DB::select('SELECT * from products where id=?', [$id]);
    $category_id = DB::table('products')->where('id', $id)->value('categories_id');
    $slug = DB::table('categories')->where('id', $category_id)->value('slug');
    $image = DB::table('products')->where('id', $id)->value('image');

    return view('products-details', compact('product','slug','image');
}
```